# Copy/paste link to file on SVN at working copy revision

Tags: windows, svn, hyperlink, tortoisesvn, explorer

I often want to send a link to a document on our SVN at a certain revision. I have found out that it is possible to access revision 123 of a_word_document.docx with the link

https://our.svn.server/the_repository/a_word_document.docx?p=123

Is there a way to get a context menu entry in windows explorer, which allows to copy a link of this format that points to the working copy revision?

I often use "TortoiseSVN > Copy URL to clipboard" - but this link always points to the head revision.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your TortoiseSVN client's version to 1.11.x

Command for copying URLs to clipboard with revision was added in TortoiseSVN 1.11.0 (see [r28385](https://osdn.net/projects/tortoisesvn/scm/svn/commits/28385) and [New Feature: "Copy versioned URL to clipboard](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/tortoisesvn/enH4fqBNU94)).